# How do I find out the URL for an article?

Tags: articles, access

I created the following article:

[image]

Which shows up in the list at

`http://localhost:81/fecms/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=articles`

I tried to navigate to

`http://localhost:81/fecms/syndication`

But I got an error

```
404 - Article not found
You may not be able to visit this page because of:

an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
a mistyped address
you have no access to this page
The requested resource was not found.
An error has occurred while processing your request.
Please try one of the following pages:

Home Page
If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and report the error below.

Article not found
```

So how do I find out the public URL of the article?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of a Joomla site is driven by the menu. So while you could access that article at
http://localhost:81/fecms/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=33

By creating a menu item called 'syndication' of a single article type and selecting your article therein you could then access the article at:

http://localhost:81/fecms/syndication